# How to call instance methods of a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's trivial to pass callback functions as props to child components, but not vice versa.

**How do we call instance methods of a child component?**

From `<Parent />` component, I need to call `this.bar` instance method of `<Child />` component.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Child />
        )
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );
        this.bar = () => console.log('foo');

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Child.method()`?

Comment: you can't. What's the use case that gives rise to this question?

Comment: @RobinZigmond I'll need to implement a `<button>` element that will call `this.bar` when it's clicked (by passing `this.bar` as `onClick`). The `<button>` element cannot be in `<Child />`

Comment: so the button is a child of `Parent`, but different from `Child`? In that case make `bar` a method of `Parent` and pass it as a prop to `Child` if you also need it there.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that either, as `this.bar` has to be defined within `Child`. I only wrote it as console.log for illustration purposes, but the use case is more complicated than that.

Comment: Why would you want to do this ? You can just change the child's properties to influence its behaviour.

Comment: The source code is here for context: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-react/blob/master/src/ckeditor.jsx  I'll need to access `this.editor` so I can call methods like `this.editor.destroy()` outside of the component

Comment: You can use a property like `destroy` and in the child override `componentDidUpdate` and call `this.editor.destroy()` when the `destroy` property is set.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `refs` to do that.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.childRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.childRef.current.bar()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child ref={this.childRef} />
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props );
    this.bar = () => console.log('foo');
  }

  render() {
    return <p>Child</p>
  }
}
```

Check out the [Refs documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)